# d3.js display image as circle

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, svg

**CODE:**

```
// some colour variables
var tcBlack = "#130C0E";

// rest of vars
var w = 1255,
h = 925,
maxNodeSize = 50,
x_browser = 10,
y_browser = 15,
root;

var vis;
var force = d3.layout.force(); 

vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

d3.json("marvel.json", function(json) {

root = json;
root.fixed = true;
root.x = w / 2;
root.y = h / 4;


    // Build the path
var defs = vis.insert("svg:defs")
  .data(["end"]);


defs.enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

 update();
});



function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
  links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

 // Restart the force layout.
 force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .gravity(0.05)
.charge(-1500)
.linkDistance(100)
.friction(0.5)
.linkStrength(function(l, i) {return 1; })
.size([w, h])
.on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var path = vis.selectAll("path.link")
  .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

path.enter().insert("svg:path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  // .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
  .style("stroke", "#eee");


// Exit any old paths.
path.exit().remove();



// Update the nodes…
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });


// Enter any new nodes.
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
  .on("click", click)
  .call(force.drag);

// Append a circle
nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(40000) / 10 || 30; })
  .style("fill", "#ffffff");

// Append images
var images = nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) { return d.img;})
    .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
    .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 50);

// make the image grow a little on mouse over and add the text details on click
var setEvents = images
      // Append hero text
      .on( 'click', function (d) {
          // d3.select("h1").html(d.hero); 
          d3.select("h3").html(d.name); 
          // d3.select("h3").html ("Take me to " + "<a href='" + d.link + "' >"  + d.hero + " web page ⇢"+ "</a>" ); 
       })

      .on( 'mouseenter', function() {
        // select element in current context
        d3.select( this )
          .transition()
          .attr("x", function(d) { return -60;})
          .attr("y", function(d) { return -60;})
          .attr("height", 100)
          .attr("width", 100);
      })
      // set back
      .on( 'mouseleave', function() {
        d3.select( this )
          .transition()
          .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
          .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
          .attr("height", 50)
          .attr("width", 50);
      });

 // Append hero name on roll over next to the node as well
 nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .attr("x", x_browser)
    .attr("y", y_browser +15)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


 // Exit any old nodes.
 node.exit().remove();


 // Re-select for update.
 path = vis.selectAll("path.link");
 node = vis.selectAll("g.node");

function tick() {


path.attr("d", function(d) {

 var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
       dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
       dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
       return   "M" + d.source.x + "," 
        + d.source.y 
        + "A" + dr + "," 
        + dr + " 0 0,1 " 
        + d.target.x + "," 
        + d.target.y;
});
node.attr("transform", nodeTransform);    
}
}



function nodeTransform(d) {
 d.x =  Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(w - (d.imgwidth/2 || 16), d.x));
 d.y =  Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(h - (d.imgheight/2 || 16), d.y));
 return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}


function click(d) {
 if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
} else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
}

 update();
}


/**
 * Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
*/ 
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = []; 
  var i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
   if (node.children) 
   node.children.forEach(recurse);
   if (!node.id) 
   node.id = ++i;
   nodes.push(node);
  }

recurse(root);
return nodes;
}
```

I'm using the above code to display image using `d3.js`. But the image is not showing as circle. I want the child node images to fill in the circle properly.

So please help to to fix this. Answers will be appreciated. Thanks
[image]

This is the example I use: [d3 | Force layout with images](http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4)

Comment: This example may help you http://jsfiddle.net/wcnxywuy/1/

Comment: I check this example before. but unfortunately  failed to fix my issue. If you help me on my code, its really appreciated.

Comment: If you can create working code we can work on it. you can check this one also http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4

Comment: You didnt show code where you try to make it a circle.

Comment: @paulitto this is the entire code I use.

Comment: @Dinesh I use the same. But for them the images they used are of circle only. thats why its perfectly showing as circle in that example.

Comment: @paulitto please refer this this link [http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4](http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4)

Comment: @Shihas in that example they are using circled images, not the square images(for sample see this [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/avengers.png)), if you want to make your images appear as circle then try to implement with Dinesh fiddle example.

Comment: @saikiran.vsk yeah I understand that and I mentioned that in above comment. Problem is Im failed to do Dinesh example as I'm a beginner to `d3.js` . So if you help me to change my code as per my requirement it will be a great help.

Comment: Ok then, we'll do it.

Comment: @saikiran.vsk will appreciate your effort brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var marvelJson={
 "name": "marvel",
 "img": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/marvel.png",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Heroes",
   "children": [
    {
      "hero": "Spider-Man",
      "name": "Peter Benjamin Parker", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/54/spider-man",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_spiderman.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "CAPTAIN MARVEL",
      "name": "Carol Danvers", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/9/captain_marvel",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_captainmarvel.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "HULK", 
      "name": "Robert Bruce Banner",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/25/hulk",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_hulk.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Black Widow", 
      "name": "Natalia 'Natasha' Alianovna Romanova",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/6/black_widow",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_blackwidow.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Daredevil", 
      "name": "Matthew Michael Murdock",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/11/daredevil",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_daredevil.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Wolverine", 
      "name": "James Howlett",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/66/wolverine",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_wolverine.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Captain America", 
      "name": "Steven Rogers",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/8/captain_america",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_captainamerica.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Iron Man", 
      "name": "Anthony Edward 'Tony' Stark",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/29/iron_man",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_ironman.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "THOR", 
      "name": "Thor Odinson",
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/60/thor",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/top_thor.png",
      "size": 40000
    }
  ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Villains",
   "children": [
    {
      "hero": "Dr. Doom",
      "name": "Victor von Doom", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/13/dr_doom",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/drdoom.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Mystique",
      "name": "Unrevealed", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1552/mystique",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/mystique.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Red Skull",
      "name": "Johann Shmidt", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1901/red_skull",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/redskull.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Ronan",
      "name": "Ronan", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/49/ronan",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/ronan.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Magneto",
      "name": "Max Eisenhardt", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/35/magneto",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/magneto.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Thanos",
      "name": "Thanos", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/58/thanos",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/thanos.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Black Cat",
      "name": "Felicia Hardy", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/271/black_cat",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/blackcat.png",
      "size": 40000
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Teams",
   "children": [
    {
      "hero": "Avengers",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/68/avengers",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/avengers.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/70/guardians_of_the_galaxy",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/gofgalaxy.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Defenders",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/534/defenders",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/defenders.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "X-Men",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/71/x-men",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/xmen.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Fantastic Four",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/69/fantastic_four",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/fantasticfour.png",
      "size": 40000
    },
    {
      "hero": "Inhumans",
      "name": "", 
      "link": "http://marvel.com/characters/1040/inhumans",
      "img":  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954023/marvel_force_chart_img/inhumans.png",
      "size": 40000
    }
   ]
  }  
 ]
}

/*
var imgurl = "http://wallpapers.androlib.com/wallicons/wallpaper.big-pqC.cs.png"

var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10};


var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var defs = svg.append("defs").attr("id", "imgdefs")

var catpattern = defs.append("pattern")
                        .attr("id", "catpattern")
                        .attr("height", 1)
                        .attr("width", 1)
                        .attr("x", "0")
                        .attr("y", "0")


catpattern.append("image")
     .attr("x", -130)
     .attr("y", -220)
     .attr("height", 640)
     .attr("width", 480)
     .attr("xlink:href", imgurl)

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 100)
    .attr("cy", 80)
    .attr("cx", 120)
    .attr("fill", "url(#catpattern)")
    */
    
    
    // some colour variables
  var tcBlack = "#130C0E";

// rest of vars
var w = 960,
    h = 800,
    maxNodeSize = 50,
    x_browser = 20,
    y_browser = 25,
    root;
 
var vis;
var force = d3.layout.force(); 

vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
 
//d3.json("marvel.json", function(json) {
 var json = marvelJson;
 
  root = json;
  root.fixed = true;
  root.x = w / 2;
  root.y = h / 4;
 
 
        // Build the path
  var defs = vis.insert("svg:defs")
      .data(["end"]);
 
 
  defs.enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
 try{
     update();
     }catch(e){
     console.log(e);
     }
//});
 
 
/**
 *   
 */
function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);
 
  // Restart the force layout.
  force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(-1500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
    .linkStrength(function(l, i) {return 1; })
    .size([w, h])
    .on("tick", tick)
        .start();
 
   var path = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
 
    path.enter().insert("svg:path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      // .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
      .style("stroke", "#eee");
 
 
  // Exit any old paths.
  path.exit().remove();
 
 
 
  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });
 
 
  // Enter any new nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
 
 
 /*Dinesh Code*/
 /*
 
 var defs = svg.append("defs").attr("id", "imgdefs")

var catpattern = defs.append("pattern")
                        .attr("id", "catpattern")
                        .attr("height", 1)
                        .attr("width", 1)
                        .attr("x", "0")
                        .attr("y", "0")


catpattern.append("image")
     .attr("x", -130)
     .attr("y", -220)
     .attr("height", 640)
     .attr("width", 480)
     .attr("xlink:href", imgurl)

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 100)
    .attr("cy", 80)
    .attr("cx", 120)
    .attr("fill", "url(#catpattern)")
    */
 
 /******* Dinesh Code End******/
 
 nodeEnter.append("defs").attr("id", "imgdefs")
 .append("pattern")
   .attr("id", function(d){ if(d.img)return d.img.replace(/[/|.|:]/g, ""); else null; })
   .attr("height", 1)
   .attr("width", 1)
   .attr("x", "0")
   .attr("y", "0")
   .append("image")
     .attr("height",  function(d) { return 2* Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
     .attr("width",  function(d) { return 2* Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
     .attr("xlink:href",  function(d){if(d.img)return d.img+""; else null; })
 
  // Append a circle
 var images = nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .attr("fill", function(d){ if(d.img)return "url(#"+d.img.replace(/[/|.|:]/g, "")+")" ; else null; });
 
   
  // Append images
 /* var images = nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) { return d.img;})
        .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("width", 50);*/
  
  // make the image grow a little on mouse over and add the text details on click
  var setEvents = images
          // Append hero text
          .on( 'click', function (d) {
              d3.select("h1").html(d.hero); 
              d3.select("h2").html(d.name); 
              d3.select("h3").html ("Take me to " + "<a href='" + d.link + "' >"  + d.hero + " web page ⇢"+ "</a>" ); 
           })

          .on( 'mouseenter', function(d) {
          if(d.img){
          //console.log(d3.select(this).parent);
          d3.select("pattern#"+d.img.replace(/[/|.|:]/g, "")).select("image").attr("width","100").attr("height","100");
            // select element in current context
            d3.select( this )
              .transition()
              .attr("x", function(d) { return -60;})
              .attr("y", function(d) { return -60;})
              .attr("r", "50")
              //.attr("height", 100)
              //.attr("width", 100);
              }
          })
          // set back
          .on( 'mouseleave', function(d) {
          if(d.img){
          d3.select("pattern#"+d.img.replace(/[/|.|:]/g, "")).select("image").attr("width","40").attr("height","40");
          
            d3.select( this )
              .transition()
              .attr("x", function(d) { return -25;})
              .attr("y", function(d) { return -25;})
              .attr("r", "20")
              //.attr("height", 50)
              //.attr("width", 50);
              }
          });

  // Append hero name on roll over next to the node as well
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("class", "nodetext")
      .attr("x", x_browser)
      .attr("y", y_browser +15)
      .attr("fill", tcBlack)
      .text(function(d) { return d.hero; });
 
 
  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();
 
 
  // Re-select for update.
  path = vis.selectAll("path.link");
  node = vis.selectAll("g.node");
 
function tick() {
 
 
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
 
     var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
           dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
           dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
           return   "M" + d.source.x + "," 
            + d.source.y 
            + "A" + dr + "," 
            + dr + " 0 0,1 " 
            + d.target.x + "," 
            + d.target.y;
  });
    node.attr("transform", nodeTransform);    
  }
}

 
/**
 * Gives the coordinates of the border for keeping the nodes inside a frame
 * http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492
 */ 
function nodeTransform(d) {
  d.x =  Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(w - (d.imgwidth/2 || 16), d.x));
    d.y =  Math.max(maxNodeSize, Math.min(h - (d.imgheight/2 || 16), d.y));
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
   }
 
/**
 * Toggle children on click.
 */ 
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
 
  update();
}
 
 
/**
 * Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
 */ 
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = []; 
  var i = 0;
 
  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) 
      node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) 
      node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }
 
  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400,600);
      body {font-family: "Source Code Pro", Consolas, monaco, monospace; line-height: 160%; font-size: 16px;  margin: 0; }
      path.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
      .node:not(:hover) .nodetext {
        display: none;
      }
      h1 { font-size: 36px; margin: 10px 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: normal;}
      h2, h3 { font-size: 18px; margin: 5px 0 ; font-weight: normal;}
      header {padding: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
      a:link { color: #EE3124; text-decoration: none;}
      a:visited { color: #EE3124; }
      a:hover { color: #A4CD39; text-decoration: underline;}
      a:active { color: #EE3124; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<section id="vis"></section>
```

After working for few hours I made something out of it, kindly observe the code changes I've made, If you can't figure it out, comment below, I'll edit my answer with full explanation.
:D

Comment: Now the nodes are ver small like this:[image](http://imgur.com/a/9NFCd). I don't know whether its coming as circle or not.

Comment: increase the r value of circle 

`// Append a circle

 var images = nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .attr("fill", function(d){ if(d.img)return "url(#"+d.img.replace(/[/|.|:]/g, "")+")" ; else null; });`

Comment: Initially it is very small while loading the page. On mouseover only it's increasing the radius.

Comment: yeah! I've written code like that, whenever on mouseover event I was increasing the radius and decreasing after mouseout event. If you want to initial radius you could change the value. Hope you find the line where exactly has to modify.

Comment: Please check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vugomsj/). Once you run check the parent node(MARVEL) it is very small. On mouseover and mouseout the radius is different.

Comment: See [Update](https://jsfiddle.net/2vugomsj/1/) I've hard coded the value, check it out.

Comment: Its working fine in JSFiddle but not in my project. Anyway thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Shihas buddy, try to observe the code changes and do it in your project.